# Mistake with decision making in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm stuck at the part of decision making. When **answer variable is N** (*when I type N it means that I don't want to print text in different lines*) and **marks variable is Y** (*when I type Y it means that I don't want to print text with quotation marks*), I'm getting message: *Answer 'Y' is invalid. Program is terminating.* Here is the code:

```
def multiFunctionalPrinter 
    puts "How many times do you want to print?"
    number = gets
    puts "-------------------------------------------"
    puts "What do you want to print?"
    text = gets.chomp                                                    #chomping variable to format it for decision making
    puts "-------------------------------------------"
    puts "Do you want to print in different lines (Y or N)?"
    answer = gets.chomp                                                  #chomping variable to format it for decision making
    puts "-------------------------------------------"
    puts "Do you want to add quotation marks (') (Y or N)?"
    marks = gets.chomp                                                   #chomping variable to format it for decision making

    if answer == "Y" && marks == "Y"                                     # Different lines: ON , Quotation marks: ON
        1.upto(number.to_i) {puts "'" + text.to_s + "'"}
    elsif answer == "Y" && marks == "N"                                  # Different lines: ON , Quotation marks: OFF
        1.upto(number.to_i) {puts text.to_s}
    elsif answer == "Y" && marks != "Y" || marks != "N"                  # Different lines: ON , Quotation marks: INVALID
        puts "Answer '#{marks}' is invalid. Program is terminating."
    elsif answer == "N" && marks == "Y"                                  # Different lines: OFF , Quotation marks: ON
        puts "Do you want to split what you print? (Y or N)"
        answer2 = gets.chomp
        if answer2 == "Y"                                                # Split: ON 
            1.upto(number.to_i) {print "'" + text.to_s + "' "}
            print "\n"
        elsif answer2 == "N"                                             # Split: OFF
            1.upto(number.to_i) {print "'" + text.to_s + "'"}
        else
            puts "Answer '#{answer2}' is invalid. Program is terminating."
        end 
    elsif answer == "N" && marks == "N"                                  # Different lines: OFF , Quotation marks: OFF
        puts "Do you want to split what you print? (Y or N)"
        answer2 = gets.chomp
        if answer2 == "Y"                                                # Split: ON
            1.upto(number.to_i) {print text.to_s + " "}
        elsif answer2 == "N"                                             # Split: OFF
            1.upto(number.to_i) {print text.to_s}
        else
            puts "Answer '#{answer}' is invalid. Program is terminating."
        end 
    else
        puts "Answer '#{answer}' or '#{marks}' is invalid. Program is terminating."
    end 
    puts "--------------------------------------------"
end 

multiFunctionalPrinter
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary operator `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.
That means that this line:

```
answer == "Y" && marks != "Y" || marks != "N"
```

Is equivalent to

```
(answer == "Y" && marks != "Y") || marks != "N"
```

So whenever `marks` is different from `"N"`, the statement holds true.

---

What you should to to solve your problem is adding a bunch of parentheses.

```
answer == "Y" && (marks != "Y" || marks != "N")
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic issue is on this line:

```
elsif answer == "Y" && marks != "Y" || marks != "N"
```

Your script is looking to see right now (answer == "Y" && marks != "Y") || marks != "N". It's evaluating the and statement before it gets  to the or statement and because answer is "N" and marks is "Y" (answer == "Y" && marks != "Y") evaluates to true.

You want to have parenthesis around the or expression so the above line will become:

```
elsif answer == "Y" && (marks != "Y" || marks != "N")
```

and the program should work as you think.